# Python Text-Based Game with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I participated in a local programming competition yesterday, where I was put on a team of four with members of varying skill levels. We were trying to make a text-based Zork style game, but since UI was one of the categories I was put on creating a GUI which I have no experience with in python. I used Tkinter and got everything mostly working inside the GUI itself, but can't figure out how to get the GUI to interact with the rest of the code.

I'm just including the relevant bits here, partially because the rest of the code is quite a mess, with no comments and lots of syntax errors, but I can post it if needed. Here's the code:

```
def pinput():
    global e
    player_input = e.get()  
    print(player_input)

def progress():
    hallway_1()

def hallway_1():
    global player_input
    global prin
    global e
    prin.set("You are in a hallway. Yellow lockers line the sides of all walls and you see three doors. One leads into a Library, one to a History classroom, and one to a Math room. You can 1.) Search the hallway or 2.) Procede to one of the rooms.")
    while player_input != "1" and player_input != "2": #Best guess at a way to get the code to wait for input, actually just causes code to freeze
        pass
    if player_input == "1": #Even if 1 is in the entry box beforehand, it never gets here
        prin.set("You search through the lockers and find 1 health potion.\n Would you like to add it to your inventory? 1.) Yes 2.) No")
        player_input = "999"

def player_attack():
    global enemy_hp
    enemy_hp -= player_strength
    prin.set("You just attacked the " + enemy_name + "!")

def player_block():
    global block
    prin.set("You predict that your enemy is going to attack and decide to block")
    block = 1

def player_use():
    global player_item_use
    global item_name
    player_item_use = 100
    prin.set("You decide to use one of your items. What do you use?")
    while player_turn_input != 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 17 or 18 or 19 or 20 or 21 or 22 or 23 or 24 or 25 or 26:
        player_item_use = e.get()
        time.sleep(1)
    item_name = Inventory[player_item_use]
    item(item_name)

def run_away():
    global player_hp
    global lost_item_1
    global lost_item_2
    prin.set("You decide to run away from the " + enemy_name + "!\nThis causes you to lose 20 health points and two inventory items.")
    player_hp -= 20
    if backpack == True:
        lost_item_1 = random.randint(1,27)
        lost_item_2 = random.randint(1,27)
    else:
        lost_item_1 = random.randint(1,9)
        lost_item_2 = random.randint(1,9)
    RemoveInventory(lost_item_1)
    RemoveInventory(lost_item_2)
    library()

top = tk.Tk()
prin = tk.StringVar()
#path = "smalllibrary.png"
#tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
#displayimage = tk.Label(top, image=tkimage).grid(row=0) 
inv = tk.Text(top, width="24")
inv.grid(row=0, column=1)
for x in Inventory:
    inv.insert("end", str(x) + str(invnum) + '\n')
    invnum += 1
healthbar = tk.Label(top, text=("Health: " + str(player_hp))).grid(row=1, column=1)
text = tk.Label(top, bg="black", fg="white", textvariable=prin, justify="left", cursor="box_spiral").grid(row=1, sticky="w")
e = tk.Entry(top)
e.grid(row=2)
e.focus_set()
Attack = tk.Button(top, text ="Attack", activebackground="red", width="10", command = player_attack).grid(row=4, sticky="e")
Block = tk.Button(top, text ="Block", activebackground="red", width="10", command = player_block).grid(row=5, sticky="e")
Use = tk.Button(top, text ="Use Item", activebackground="red", width="10", command = player_use).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
Run = tk.Button(top, text ="Run", activebackground="red", width="10", command = run_away).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="w")
Enter = tk.Button(top,text='Enter',command=pinput).grid(row=3)
Progress = tk.Button(top, text="Progress", activebackground="green", 
prin.set("REDACTED")#This had my team's full names

top.mainloop()
```

So, there are a few problems. I added the "progress" button for testing purposes, ideally the game would start in Hallway 1. However, I couldn't figure out where to put the hallway_1() function for this to work. Before the top.mainloop() and the GUI wouldn't open. After it, and e.get() threw TCL errors.

So, I bound it to a button. However, now the code keeps getting stuck in the "while" loop even if 1 is inputted into the entry box before the code runs. I'm perplexed by this because Visual Studio reports player_input as being '1' in the Autos box, but it keeps running through the loop anyway.

Comment: You can't do a `while` loop like that in a GUI event handler. Until you return from the handler function, the GUI doesn't get to update its display, accept user input, or do anything else, which means `player_input` will never change once you get there. A handler function needs to do one thing, set up anything needed for future handlers, and return immediately.

Comment: Okay I see, but I still don't understand why the loop runs even if player_input is equal to '1'

Comment: Ah, that's another problem—you just forgot `global player_input` in `pinput`, so you're only creating a local variable with the same name. The global variable _isn't_ `"1"`. However, given the code you have here, that should raise a `NameError`.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a `while` loop like that in a GUI event handler. Until you return from the handler function, the GUI doesn't get to update its display, accept user input, or do anything else, which means player_input will never change once you get there. A handler function needs to do one thing, set up anything needed for future handlers, and return immediately.

It's hard to get your head around thinking in terms of the event loop and handler callbacks the first time you write a GUI, but it's absolutely essential; until you do, things seem bizarre and arbitrary.

So, the answer isn't to "wait for input", but to set up a handler that fires when that input is ready. (You *can* instead set up a handler on an `after` function so it fires every N milliseconds instead of firing on input, but that usually just makes things more complicated.)

One way to do this is to have the "Progress" button trigger "the next step", and keep track of some state that lets you determine what "the next step" is. An in fact, you already *have* that state: it's whether the player has already given correct input or not. So:

```
def pinput():
    global player_input
    player_input = e.get()  
    print(player_input)

def progress():
    pinput()
    if player_input != "1" and player_input != "2":
        hallway_1_enter()
    else:
        hallway_1_doit()

def hallway_1_enter():
    global player_input
    global prin
    global e
    prin.set("You are in a hallway. Yellow lockers line the sides of all walls and you see three doors. One leads into a Library, one to a History classroom, and one to a Math room. You can 1.) Search the hallway or 2.) Procede to one of the rooms.")

def hallway_1_doit():
    if player_input == "1": #Even if 1 is in the entry box beforehand, it never gets here
        # etc.
```

This is obviously a bit of a clunky design, but it's the smallest change to your existing design that gets you past the first step. Once you get the hang of it, you should be able to improve it from there.

Also notice the `global player_input` I put in `pinput`. Your existing function didn't have that, so it was just creating a local variable with the same name, which then goes away immediately; the global never gets changed. Any function that wants to assign to a global needs the `global` statement.